# How can I determine the direction of current and how many different currents there are?

Tags: current, kirchhoffs-laws

Whenever there are circuits with many batteries in parallel I get confused and I don't k now the direction of each current or whether it's the same current flowing or another.

[image]

Comment: Generally you assume a clockwise current flow around each loop and let the sign of the resultant voltage tell you whether it's reversed or not.

Comment: Is there any more information given in this particular problem? Can we assume all the batteries (E1, E2 and E3)  are equal voltage? Otherwise I am not sure it can be solved.

Answer (score 1):

*You* (or the one asking test questions) are the one setting the arrows. The resulting currents are either positive or negative.

There's no "right" way to set the current arrows – there might be notation that make more or less sense practically. Often, one chooses the current arrows so that most of the resulting numbers are positive, but honestly, that doesn't make a difference; whether I say

> 1 A are flowing from the positive end of the battery to the negative through the resistor

Or

> -1 A are flowing from the negative end of the battery to the positve through the resistor

makes *no difference at all*. Both statements are *exactly the same*.

Because your tags mention "Kirchhoff's laws": of course, if I state something like:

> The sum of all currents **flowing into** a node is 0,

then that means that all arrows need to point *into* the node. But that usually just means you "in head* convert the current sign so that it's measured with an arrow pointing into the node; that's all.

Comment: But the question on the exercise asks for the dierction of the current near battery 1 and battery 2

Comment: well, when you want a positive current to flow, which direction do you draw the arrow?

Answer (score 1):

Here the author showed an arrow out of each battery to show positive if flowing out. But highest voltage or rather the voltage differences will determine the polarity or actual resulting direction of current.  So here an **+i** shown going out.

If **i** becomes -ve from voltage differences later, then you know it is being charged up.  So the initial assumption of direction is arbitrary, yet clockwise, CW is the convention.

You will find there are 2 basic methods of solving and neither cares on your initial assumption of polarity is correct  (positive) or not.

1. Branch Method uses both KVL & KCL
2. Mesh Method uses just KVL in all current loops is easier for complex networks.